# java: String index out of range: 6

Tags: java, string, exception, loops

I get the following error in my java code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6

...which occurs at the following line:

```
if (strFactor.charAt(j) == strProduct.charAt(k)) {
```

Here is the code:

```
       for (int j=0; 0<=5; j++) {
            same = false;
            for (int k=0; k<=5; k++) {
                if (strFactor.length() == 6 && strProduct.length() == 6) {
                    if (strFactor.charAt(j) == strProduct.charAt(k)) {
                        same = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!same) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Anyone have any idea why the index would ever be out of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Java programmer, but `0<=5` will always evaluate to `true`, so `j` reaches `6` (and would keep going were it not for that exception).

Comment: you have no idea how long i've fretted over this. thanks for pointing out my stupidity! :)

Comment: There have got to be better ways of solving this problem, but that wasn't the question being asked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`for (int j=0; 0<=5; j++) {` should be `for (int j=0; j<=5; j++) {`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first line of your forloop. The string is going out of bounds

```
for (int j=0; 0<=5; j++) {
```

Correct the condition. Always be careful when you code !! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Hey man: Your j_for is wrong...It should be for(int j=0; j<=5; j++),but you write 0<=5